# syntax highlighter doesn't detect new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

I'm using this plugin to highlight textarea :

http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/jQuery-Based-Text-Highlighter-For-Textarea.html

```
$('textarea').textareaHighlighter({
  matches: [
   {
      'match': ['hello','dear','this is a test', 'text to match'], // will check for this matches
      'matchClass': 'match'             // on matched text this class will be added
    }
  ]
});
```

the color appear, but not in the good places, it doesn't detect ending of line.

[image]

when I activate the debug mode :

```
$('textarea').textareaHighlighter({
    debug: true,
    matches: [
         {
      'match': ['hello','dear','this is a test', 'text to match'], // will check for this matches
      'matchClass': 'match'             // on matched text this class will be added
    },
        {
            'match': /([\%'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g,
            'matchClass': 'tags'
        }
    ]
});
```

i get this result :
[image]

**here is a demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/9at1jgfv/1/

Comment: can you show live demo| jsfiddle ?

Comment: @FastSnail: okey :)

Comment: @FastSnail: I update the post with a link demo

Comment: It's not highlighting what you've entered because it takes the string of what you entered then inserts again with highlight spans. You can see this happening clearly in your jsfiddle.

My suggestion would be to hide the current text then show in another area the changes this would negate the issues you are having.

Comment: @MattStephens: the debug mode is set to true, try demo with debug:false

Comment: It's the same the text is still there it's just transparent.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the newlines, remove them and you still have the issue.

Comment: @ilyas mimouni it seems that plugin is very buggy .is there any demos provided by them.may be it's time to try another plugin

Comment: @FastSnail: I see this demo, apparently it works : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Based-Text-Highlighter-For-Textarea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after one hour of search in the website source :
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Based-Text-Highlighter-For-Textarea/

I found the solution, by adding a class :

```
    .target {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 3px;
        resize: none;
        white-space: pre-wrap;      <----------------- the magic solution
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }


<textarea class="target" name="message" required="true" style="width:600px; height:470px;">  hello,

  I'm using this is a test.

  thank you dear
</textarea>
```

and i hope this will help someone in the future.